# Can a wired PC access a wireless printer?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

My mom has a windows PC with a wired connection to a home router.  The PC itself does not have a wifi connection, but the router can do wired and wireless connections.

She wants my recommendation to buy a printer.  Can her PC use a wireless printer via the router?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.

I truly recommend Wired Printers (Ethernet) but Wireless Printers will work for sure.

Set up the Printer, set the Network settings to be a Static IP on the router (can be wireless).

Set all the settings:  IP, Subnet Mask (255.255.255.255) and Gateway (the router local IP address).  Save those settings.  Restart the Printer and you should be all set.

Why a static IP?  To prevent changes if the printer is restarted or like event.

With the Printer ON, install the Printer Driver on the computer.

I have seen this done / set it up for people and it works well.

Comment: What @John suggests here is EXACTLY the way my system is setup.  My primary PC is ethernet to the router and the printer (Brother in this case) sits in another room on the WiFi.  Works every time.  You don't NEED to do the static IP *but as John suggests*, it will make your life easier in the long run and you won't need to come do tech support when the router burps out a new IP address.